# Center text in Game engine with python

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to get a bitmap text centered in my game.
The text is generated at start, so I wan't to scale & translate it based in its dimensions after the text has been set. This my current code.

```
text = str(scenesInfo[i][1])
tempBotonText['Text'] = text
textScaleX = 1/len(text)
tempBotonText.localScale[0] *= textScaleX
tempBotonText.localPosition[0] -=len(texto)  * 0.008
```

But as you can see, the number I am using in the translation is just a guess, and it doesn't work well with any length.

Is there a way I can know the dimensions of the text (it is a bitmap text) after its creation?

Comment: It's hard to figure our what you're doing. What is `tempBotonText`?

Comment: I've always worked around this by using monospaced fonts.  But you might have some luck with blf.dimensions(fontID, "text here").  It returns a 2-float tuple containing width and height.  http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/blf.html